# Property [articles] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this code in my model called Tag:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'tag'
    ];

    public function articles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

and I use this code in my controller

```
 public function fillter($target){
        $tags = tag::where('id', 3)->count();
        $article = $tags->articles;

        foreach ($article as $article){
            return $article->title;
        }

    }
```

when I run the code, I get an exception:
 **Property [articles] does not exist on this collection instance.**

but if I am able to run the following code:

```
$tags = tag::where('id', 3)->first();
```

Comment: Does the tag with id 3 actually have articles?

Comment: @Collin That should not matter. If there were no articles, it should just return an empty collection. Instead this happens when you call a model method on a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are practically trying to get articles from integer value, since that is what `count()` function returns. This line of code returns an integer:

```
$tags = tag::where('id', 3)->count(); // For ex: 3
```

And you are trying to do this in the next line of code:

```
$article = 3->articles; //Which doesn't exist
```

By using this line of code here:

```
$tags = tag::where('id', 3)->first();
```

You are returning a `Tag` instance, which in fact has the `articles` property.

Also, your `foreach` code won't work because of two reasons:

**First**: You can't use same variable in your foreach loop, it should be like
    this:

```
foreach($articles as $article)
```

**Second**: It will stop executing after the first loop, since you have a return statement:

```
foreach ($articles as $article){
     return $article->title;
}
```

It would be better to pass the `$articles` variable to your view, and do a foreach loop there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful not to mix up models and collections.

The Tag model has articles, and a collection of Tags does not. Also, it does not make sense to return in the for-loop as you do, as it would return on the very first element. I suppose you want a list of all titles related to a Tag. I think that can be expressed as something like this:

```
$tags = tag::where('id', 3)->with('articles')->get();
return $tags->pluck('articles')->pluck('title');
```